# Using SymPy to solve complex systems containing Abs() operation

Tags: python, sympy

when trying to use *SymPy* to solve a system like this (where **R2 is a real number**, **Z3 is an imaginary number**, and every other variables is complex):

```py
I1, I2, I3, Z3 = symbols("I1, I2, I3, Z3", real = False)
R2 = symbols("R2", real = True)

f1 = I2 * R2 - 220
f2 = I3 * Z3 - 220
f3 = Abs(I1) - 4
f4 = Abs(I2) - 2
f5 = Abs(I3) - 3

solve([f1, f2, f3, f4, f5], [I1, I2, I3, R2, Z3])
```

I ran into an error like:

```
NotImplementedError: solving Abs(I1) when the argument is not real or imaginary.
```

I went to see the document of SymPy and made it sure that the `Abs()` function could return a complex number's module, and btw it works well if all the variables are real.

So why does this error occur? and how should I solve my equations? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the definition of Abs for a complex number to get a solution in this case:

```
_abs = Abs # save definition

Abs = lambda x: sqrt(re(x)**2 + im(x)**2)
I1, I2, I3, Z3 = symbols("I1, I2, I3, Z3", real=False)
R2 = symbols("R2", real = True)
f1 = I2 * R2 - 220
f2 = I3 * Z3 - 220
f3 = Abs(I1) - 4
f4 = Abs(I2) - 2
f5 = Abs(I3) - 3

eq=solve([f1, f2, f3, f4, f5], [I1, I2, I3, R2, Z3])

Abs = _abs # restore definition
```

This gives

```
[{
    re(I1): (I1**2 + 16)/(2*I1), 
    im(I1): I*(16 - I1**2)/(2*I1), 
    re(I2): (R2**2 + 12100)/(110*R2), 
    im(I2): I*(R2**2 - 12100)/(110*R2), 
    re(I3): (9*Z3**2 + 48400)/(440*Z3), 
    im(I3): I*(9*Z3**2 - 48400)/(440*Z3), 
    I2: 220/R2, 
    I3: 220/Z3}]
```

But I think you would need 3 extra conditions to resolve the real and imaginary components explicitly.

From `f1` you know that I2 must be real so `im(I2) = 0` so `R2 = sqrt(12100)`. Do you have 2 other conditions?

Maybe the reason that `solve` refuses to deal with complex arguments for `Abs` is for this reason: unless you know it's real or imaginary, you aren't going to get an explicit solution.

Comment: I guess I did miss some conditions, and thanks for your solution. But I start to wonder why it cannot conduct  that `im(I2) = 0` with equation `f1`?